# storing php variable in session and calling into pagination link

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

At the moment i'm calling the following via GET

```
$RimWidth = $_GET['RimWidth'];
$TyreWidth = $_GET['TyreWidth'];
$Aspect = $_GET['Aspect'];
$TyreDia = $_GET['TyreDia'];
$TyreMan = $_GET['TyreMan'];
```

However in my paginiation, after page 1 it looses the variables and doesn't work. I understand i need to store them in the session. How do i do this as i've seen a few way of doing it and can't get it to work and how do i place them onto the end of the pagination links which look like this

```
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
```

thanks

Comment: What did you try? This is basic, there are lots of [examples in the manual](http://us1.php.net/manual/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: You shouldn't need to add them to the end of your pagination links, they're session variables and will be available on the next page, or any page.

Answer (score 0):

You need this at the top of your PHP pages if using sessions:

```
session_start();
```

Then, you should really do this for each one:

```
$RimWidth = isset($_GET['RimWidth']) ? trim(strip_tags($_GET['RimWidth'])) : null;
$_SESSION['RimWidth'] = $RimWidth;
// and so on
```

`trim()` and `strip_tags()` removes any unwanted white-space and removes any malicious script tags being sent to your page. Never trust any POST, GET or SESSION data. They can all be compromised by hackers. If RimWidth always returns an integer, then put `(int)` before, like this:

```
(int) $RimWidth = isset($_GET['RimWidth']).............
```

You shouldn't need to add the session variables to the end of your pagination links, they're session variables and will be available on the next page, or any other page.

To call them on another page, do this:

```
echo $_SESSION['RimWidth'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just repeat the $_GET values, you can make a function to do that:

```
//A function to get and repeat arguments in every link
function repeatvars(){
  if(isset($_GET) && empty($_GET) == false){
    $variables = "?";
    $arraycount = count($_GET) - 1;
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($_GET as $var => $value){
      if(empty($value) == true){
        $variables .= $var;
      }else{
        $variables .= $var."=".$value;
      }
      if ($count !== $arraycount){
        $variables .= "&";
      }
      $count++;
    }
    return $variables;
  }}

//Example
echo '<a href="nextpage.php'.repeatvars().'">Next Page</a> (Link: nextpage.php'.repeatvars().')';
```